# Is it possible to do negative tag filter for email subscription?

Tags: support

I'm trying to set up a [ASP.NET/C# tag filter for daily email](https://stackexchange.com/filters/27884/my-filter). But if I do that, there are way more questions than I can cope with.

Is it possible to do a negative filter, e.g. -VB.NET -Crystal-Reports ?

Is it possible to and AND, e.g. only questions with both ASP.NET and the C# tag?