# Negative filtering in "Create a filter"

Tags: feature-request, filtering

The "Create a filter" option on the stackexchange.com/questions page gives one the ability to display "Just questions tagged with the xxx tag". But one of the nice things about Stackexchange is the ability to view Q&A on a broad variety of topics. Still, there are a few topics/sites for which one may have no interest whatsoever. For me, that would include rpg, scifi, and tex. It would be great if filtering would allow one to specify negatives, that is, "Don't give me any results that contain tags xxx or are from sites yyy".

Sounds like this question has already been asked several times. For instance, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions), but I'd like this filter to apply not necessarily only to the "hot questions", and it remains unanswered. Another [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114351/is-it-possible-to-do-negative-tag-filter-for-email-subscription) mentions negative filtering, but in the context of email subscriptions, and the answer indicates the facility is not available, so here is a feature request.

Answer (score 5):

You can switch the radio button from 'All sites' to 'Just these sites', and then leave the boxes for rpg, scifi, and tex unchecked:

[image]

Here, I've discluded/negative filtered the foreign L&U sites and TeX.

This is tedious if your question is on many sites, and won't capture new sites if they add your tag after you create the filter (sites which don't currently have the tag aren't shown), so I agree that your feature request has merit.  However, it's mostly possible right now.

Comment: +1 Very good workaround, solves 95% of the issue. Tedious setup not a problem, since you can save the filter. The main thing is, one can still see the hot questions from a wide variety of preferred sites.