# How can I suppress notifications from non-English sites?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email, languages

I have a "lisp" filter and I regularly get notifications from non-English SE sites ([Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), etc.) about [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29)-related questions.

I do ***not*** want to limit my filter to specific sites (e.g., [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) or [Emacs](http://emacs.stackexchange.com)), rather, I want to ***exclude*** all **non-English**/*foreign-language-specific* sites - i.e., sites defined by *language* rather than *topic* (even if I happen to know those languages or even speak them natively).

Is there a way to do that?

**PS**. Please note that no inclusion/exclusion per-site selection would be enough: I want to **exclude** all *future* language-specific sites, and **include** all *future* topic-specific sites, and **include** all *existing* topic-specific sites that might add the interesting tags in the *future* --- ***automatically***.

Comment: Only way is to choose the sites you want under "Just these sites" when you create/edit the filter.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: this is exactly what I do _NOT_ want to do!

Comment: Fair, so what you ask for is impossible.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard That would turn this question into a feature-request then.

Comment: Admittedly, yes, it's a bit of a pain to click the checkboxes for nearly every site. Having "select all" and "select none" buttons would be convenient. It's unclear to me if a "select all English sites" is good, given that some of the language sites can be in English or the language for the site.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: You could run any of the following in the console: select all `$('.sites-list input[type="checkbox"]:visible').prop('checked', true);` select none: `$('.sites-list input[type="checkbox"]:visible').prop('checked', false)` toggle: `$('.sites-list input[type="checkbox"]:visible').click()`

Comment: You say "I do not want to limit my filter to specific sites", but that's *exactly* what excluding non-English sites is. It's limiting your filter to specific sites (i.e. all English sites). What you appear to be asking for is, basically, for SE to both A) define which sites are non-English and B) give you a checkbox/button which makes it easy for you to select just the English sites from the list of checkboxes which "limit my filter to specific sites". In other words, your question is poorly worded and appears potentially contradictory without making assumptions about what you're wanting.

Comment: @Makyen **No, it is absolutely not the same.** The OP does not want to have to manually specify sites one-by-one, they're looking for an English/non-English boolean filter that will continue to work in the future without having to regularly go back and check all the sites manually to see which ones are not in English. There will (presumably) continue to be new SE sites added regularly.

Comment: @Makyen Not to mention existing sites which later on create a tag about a subject

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for has never been available.

The closest you can get is when you create your filter do not use all sites or add non-English sites:

> [image]

To edit an existing filter: click on your filter, the edit link is in the upper left corner. There is approximately a half dozen non-English sites to leave off of the list.

This answer is similar to the answer provided at the duplicate: "[Negative filtering in 'Create a filter'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134045/282094) ".

Comment: This is exactly what I do _NOT_ want to do!

Comment: I read a similar comment above, perhaps you should clarify your question; now that two people misunderstood it.

Comment: the 2nd paragraph is specifically dedicated to this.

Comment: You've made no change, only bolded existing words. Help us to help you. Please explain how what we offer differs from what you ask. This ***is*** how to: "... sites that are topic-specific/English-only and exclude non-English/foreign-language-specific sites.".

Comment: Instead of "Just these sites", @sds wants to have "Except these sites" option.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard - not just "except these" - I don't want to have to list _all_ the non-english sites _explicitly_. I want to exclude _all_ sites defined by _language_ rather than _topic_.

Comment: @sds all sites are defined by language *and* topic, just for most of them it's English.